# Suppress "cannot instantiate non-constructor" warning

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Using the Closure Compiler,I get the warning:

> cannot instantiate non-constructor

This is just a warning and the code runs fine. Still, I hate having warnings that I know have no affect on the app. Some of the code where this warning occurs is from third party libraries but some of it is from my own.

Is there a way to just suppress this warning?

Comment: Do you need any more help with this?  If you give more details on the error perhaps someone can help more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this option:

```
--warnings_whitelist_file VAL          : A file containing warnings to
                                          suppress. Each line should be of the
                                          form
                                          <file-name>:<line-number>? 
                                          <warning-description> (default: )
```

This might be useful to suppress warnings from the 3rd party code:

```
--hide_warnings_for VAL                : If specified, files whose path
                                          contains this string will have their
                                          warnings hidden. You may specify
                                          multiple.
```

There is also this:

```
--warning_level (-W) [QUIET | DEFAULT  : Specifies the warning level to use.
 | VERBOSE]                               Options: QUIET, DEFAULT, VERBOSE
                                          (default: DEFAULT)
```

To see the complete list of available options execute a command like this:

```
java -jar ../closure-compiler/target/closure-compiler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --help
```

Note however that you are passing up some of the benefits of Closure Compiler for doing type-checking on your code.  If you provide more details about the error and where in the code it happened I might be able to suggest the annotation to use there.

Answer (score 0):

For you own code, either use ES2015 class syntax, or add `@constructor` annotations to function constructors. This tells the compiler that the function is intended to be called with the `new` operator.

For 3rd party code, hiding the warning is the best you can do.